# Migrating SSDT from 2015 to 2019 Breaks Script Component

Tags: migration, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I just migrated from SSDT 2015 to SSDT 2019 and tried to open a project created in SSDT 2015. One of the packages has a data flow task with a script component in it.  The script component fails to build with the error:

> Could not find part of the path
> 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\c2e811fdc5974e2ca3f7cb5426c82033_out'

I tried to delete the .vs folder in my project but that didn't work.  The script still fails to rebuild.  The script has a lot of classes in it so I'd rather not start from scratch and copy everything into it.  Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: One thing to add... I tried creating an empty script task in the same package.  It also won't build for the same reason, though the path has a different set of letters & numbers at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Appears this issue may be caused by an incompatibility between Visual Studio 16.9 and SQL Server Integration Services Projects.  The issue is described here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

Recommendation is to regress back to Visual Studio 16.8 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of data tools fixed it for me without rolling back to 16.8.  This was a difficult issue to resolve.  Nowhere in the MS documentation do they mention the tools update fixes that specific error.  Thanks for the link!